# awk multiple passes on each line

Tags: bash, awk

I have to process some large files and running multiple tests on each line. I am currently using awk to run individual tests, and using a "while-read-line-do" loop to pass each line to a dozen of so awk commands that test various columns to validate their contents and log the errors. The lines that pass all the tests are appended to a .VALID file.

The problem I face currently is that this process is extremely slow. From what I gather after reading many other posts around the web and on StackOverflow, is that the main culprit is the "while-read-line-do" loop which does not loan the files (around 100K lines each) into memory.

I was hoping that someone here could help me figure out a better way to implement things so that I can get an awk-like performance. Here's a simplified version of my code :

```
while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]];do
    echo $line | awk -F\; '{
        if ( ($3 != "P") && ($3 != "0") ) {print $0 "; ERROR ;" >> "INPUT_FILE.ERRORS"};
            else print $0 >> "INPUT_FILE.OK";
        }'
    echo $line | awk -F\; '{
        if ( ($7 < 10) || ($7 > 3) ) {print $0 "; ERROR ;" >> "INPUT_FILE.ERRORS"};
            else print $0 >> "INPUT_FILE.OK";
        }'  
    echo $line | awk -F\; '{
        if ( ($36 < 0) || ($36 > 1000) ) {print $0 "; ERROR ;" >> "INPUT_FILE.ERRORS"};
            else print $0 >> "INPUT_FILE.OK";
        }'
done < INPUT_FILE.txt
```

Ideally I'm trying to come up with a solution that allows me to have multiple passes per line using an awk-based loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just put all the awk blocks/tests into a single script and don't use `next` or anything to skip the line. awk runs all blocks against each line. You don't need multiple awk runs or the read loop here at all.

Comment: Hi @EtanReisner. Thanks for your quick reply. I'm not quite sure how to loop through the lines with awk, as opposed to "while read line do". Could you please indulge me a bit and share a quick example. Thanks again !

Comment: `if ( ($7 < 10) || ($7 > 3) )` seems like there is an error in this condition, since it is always true. Should it maybe be `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: You don't loop in awk. awk loops for you. awk runs the entire script you give it over each line automatically. Just give it the file and all your blocks/patterns/if statements/etc.

Comment: @TimZimmermann I constructed a quick example, as my conditions are a little complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's absolutely no need pass the lines to awk one by one; awk processes files line by line on your behalf. The code in your answer could be reduced to this:

```
awk -F\; '($3!="P"&&$3!="0")||($7<10||$7>3)||($36<0||$36>1000)
          {print $0 "; ERROR ;" >> "INPUT_FILE.ERRORS"; next}
          {print >> "INPUT_FILE.OK"}' INPUT_FILE.txt
```

I suspect that this will be a lot faster.

The structure of an awk program is `condition { action }`, so it is rarely the case that you need to use `if`/`else`. Instead, you can use `next` in the `if` branch, which means that awk will skip to the next line instead of running the second block.

The output from this will be slightly different, as lines that fail more than one of the tests will not be duplicated in the error log. I assumed that this was OK, as the output for each of your checks was the same anyway.

For further improvements in performance, you could consider arranging the tests in order of likeliness, as this will mean that the condition is more likely to short-circuit.

Note that in awk, `>` and `>>` have a different meaning to in the shell. `>` will mean that awk creates a new file the first time and appends to it on successive writes, so you may want to use that. If the file doesn't already exist, it doesn't really matter though.

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like there is a logical error with `$7<10||$7>3` as this is always true. Perhaps you got the `>` and `<` mixed up?

If you want to write separate output for each error, you can change the structure slightly to something like this:

```
awk -F\; '{f=0}
          $3!="P"&&$3!="0" {print $0 "; ERROR ;" >> "INPUT_FILE.ERRORS"; f=1}
          $7<3||$7>10      {print $0 "; ERROR ;" >> "INPUT_FILE.ERRORS"; f=1}
          $36<0||$36>1000  {print $0 "; ERROR ;" >> "INPUT_FILE.ERRORS"; f=1}
          !f {print >> "INPUT_FILE.OK"}' INPUT_FILE.txt
```

Each test is made separately and `f` is set to true if any of the tests are true. If `f` is still false after all tests on the line, it is printed to the OK file. I also switched your second test around so that it is not always true.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While this is definitely faster, unfortunately this wouldn't do the trick for me.

I need to perform each test on each line, and log the respective errors. So if a line does not meet 3 out of the 12 conditions, all three errors are to be logged. And finally the line should not go into the .VALID file if any of the tests don't pass.

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide a suggestion that prints separate lines for each test.